# where should i put lastlogin in yii2?

Tags: yii2

i have a lastlogin attribute for User model, but where to put the lastlogin? i'm using the default yii2-advanced template.

```
$model=User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id)
$model->lastlogin=time();
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store $model->lastlogin you must first change the database table (eg user) by adding the field that interests you, then update the model of the user by extending or modifying, remmenber of updating its rules.
I think the more appropriate place to enter this field is the user table and the related class ie the User model.

Comment: i've already have a user table and a lastlogin column in it. i want to now where to put this save action?like beforesave()? is there a behavior like afterlogin()?

Comment: In SIteController actionLogin just before the redirection to goBack